# Provides a 10 Degree-Of-Freedom IMU reduntant data?

Tags: imu, sensor-fusion

Basic question concerning sensor fusion:

A standard 10 DoF IMU, I mean this cheap things for the tinkerer at home, provides 10 values:
3 Accelerometers
3 Gyroscope
3 Magnetic Field Measurements
1 Pressure sensor (+ 1 Temperature)

I know that the accel-data provide long term stability, but are useless for short term and the gyroscope is more or less vice versa.

So there are tons of strategies to "marry" this values, but how does the magnetic field measurement fit into this framework?

Basically the magnetic field measurement should provide an attitude, too. Like the other two sensors combined. I guess this measurement alone is neither reliable.

So how do all these sensors fit together?

BR

Answer (score 1):

The magnetometer is an electric compass. If you know the magnetic field that you are operating in, you should be able to tell which direction you're pointing in.

All three sensors can be fused together to give you an accurate estimate of attitude. This can be done using a nonlinear kalman filter.

Using only the accelerometer and the gyro, vehicle heading cannot be measured. You can integrate the gyro measurements but you have no way to account for drift. That is what the magnetometer brings to the system.

Comment: How do they fit together, if I implement a Kalman estimator, I do not see the point where these sensor data are needed. For me it does fit fine together, like it is.

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking. Could you rephrase your question?

Comment: @TobiasK - I have to agree with holmeski. I'm not sure what you're trying to say.